# Use printf to print the values referenced by an array of pointers

Tags: assembly, 64-bit

The image shows how I have loaded the addresses of the Array of 10 byte elements as the values to a pointer array.  I intend to sort this array, LATER.

For now I am stuck trying to dereference these stored addresses to use c++ printf function to print actual array values to screen from that Ptr array.

I have no problem printing out the Array of elements by calling printf, which looks something like

```
fld tword [Array] 
fstp tword [rsp]
mov rsi,rsp 
mov rdi, "String which is defined above %Lf ..." 
call printf
```

Any ideas for doing something similar to this if my array values hold the pointer addresses?

[image]

Comment: TWORD? Are these IEEE 80-bit floating point values?

Comment: The values on the array are 80-bit.  My professor told us the pointers to the data are 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` is still going to expect your floating point value on stack, so (off the top of my head) that could be something like

```
mov rax, offset [Pts]
fld tword [rax] 
fstp tword [rsp]
mov rsi,rsp 
mov rdi, "String which is defined above %Lf ..." 
call printf
```

Comment: I follow, this should work.  It's printing out all 0.0 for the results, which makes me think my Pointer array creation is messed up somewhere.  Thank you very much for the response.  I will let you know if I get it!  Take care.

Comment: I figured it out.  I had a similar solution but I was trying to mov straight to rsp, which I forgot is not allowed.  The only adjustment to your solution is to bracket Pts.  Thanks again!